# Inconsistent ContentDocument Query Results

Tags: soql, contentdocument

Using the Developer Console as System Admin:

The result of this query:
SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument

does NOT contain the row returned from this query:
SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id='069xxxxxxxxx'

I've also tried ContentVersion.ContentDocumentId queries - also no luck.

The Salesforce UI does show that record to me (I can upload new versions for example).

Is there a better way (Apex) to get all ContentDocument  records?

Answer (score 1):

Are you the record owner? 
If no, then it looks like a known issue:
[Obtaining all ContentDocument records using SOQL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2206/obtaining-all-contentdocument-records-using-soql)