# Mistake is SOQL query

Tags: soql, contentversion, contentdocument

When I searck content document by Id I see the result, but when I search by title the result is missing. The problem appears when someone else create document. When I create documents, everything is OK.

[image]

[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: I would assume this is because you don't have sharing access to the other users' documents.

Comment: Even if I System administrator?

Comment: I guess it depends on your "administrator" profile. Check to see if you have View All Data permission for the relevant objects around content documents.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now everything is OK

Comment: I suggest posting the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that by default even System Administrator can't see all ContentDocuments. That's why we need to assign Permission Set for user to view all Data.

Full path: Setup->Permission Sets -> (choose an existing or create a new one) ->App Permission -> Under the 'Content' section you will see 'Query All Files'.

Phil W help me to find right answer.

The question that helped me: [Obtaining all ContentDocument records using SOQL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2206/obtaining-all-contentdocument-records-using-soql)