# SOQL Query for ContentDocument

Tags: soql, contentdocument

I ran this query below

> select id, owner.name, ownerid, title from contentdocument where id =
> '0695i000007L0FIAA0'

I got this results which shows me the owner id

[image]

I then ran another query trying to find all records which belonged to the owner from the above query. But it shows nothing

> select id, owner.name, ownerid, title from contentdocument where
> ownerid = '0052j000000M0XtAAK'

I've noticed on the ContentDocument object when i run a query it doesnt show everything. Is that supposed to happen? I'm not able to find all the records for certain queries but if I use a different query i get different results which is confusing.

Anyone able to shed some light on this?

[image]

Comment: this must be some limitation of the tool you are using; `Select id, ownerId, title from ContentDocument where ownerId = '0052j000000M0XtAAK'` if executed in a soql builder will definitely return the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try with below query i am able to get the contentDocument records based on ownerid.

```
   select id, owner.name, ownerid, title from contentdocument where ownerid = '0052j000000M0XtAAK'
```

> By default, users (including users with the “View All Data”
> permission) can only query files they have access to, including:
>
> 1. Salesforce Files in their personal library and in libraries they're a member
>    of, regardless of library permissions (API version 17.0 and later).
> 2. Salesforce Files they own, shared directly with them, posted on their profile,
>    or posted on groups they can see (API version 21.0 and later).
>
> Enable the Query All Files permission to let your View All Data users
> bypass the restrictions on querying files.
>
> 1. Query All Files returns all files, including files in non-member libraries and
>    files in unlisted groups.
> 2. Users can’t edit, upload new versions, or delete files they don’t have access
>    to.
> 3. View All Data permission is required to enable Query All Files.

Refer the [Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm)

Refer [Obtaining all ContentDocument records using SOQL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2206/obtaining-all-contentdocument-records-using-soql)